# What is the simplest way to host a qgis2web export?

Tags: qgis, web-mapping, qgis2web, hosting

I am new to hosting web maps and would like to know how I can run a qgis2web export and embed a webmap url to sharepoint or share with others. How can this be done open source?

Comment: If using Sharepoint https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/162019/is-there-a-way-to-host-static-html-using-office-365-sharepoint

Answer (score 2):

You must have access to a web server and webspace, than you can save your files there. If you know how to install and setup a webserver, you could set up your own Apache Server (OpenSource), see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_HTTP_Server. However, if you had that knowledge, you wouldn't have asked here.

If you work for an insitution, you might use their website to publish content there. However, websites today (at least those of bigger companies, universities etc.) often use a CMS (Content management system) where you don't have direct access to the webserver space. The CMS is an intermediate, often WYSYWYG ([what you see is what you get](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WYSIWYG)) interface between you and the server. So normally you can't just create individual folders manually and upload the output of qgis2web there. CMS are here to make it easy for different persons to quickly create and edit sites without the need to know anything about webservers and website programming (html, css, javascript, php etc.). So a company or institution can create a corporate design and staff with access to the CMS has only limited possibilities to change the content. That sayed: the advantage is an easy to use way to enable a broad range of people to edit the content of websites. The disadvantage is that you don't have direct access to the server and webspace. So often you will not be able to create manually new folders and upload the output of qgis2web there. In this case, you should contact the IT department of your institution.

Another option is to hire webspace. There are companies offering commercial webhosting where you get folders that are accessible in the www. This is what you do when you want to create your own website, often using your proper URL like `www.myurl.net`. You normally should be able to upload content you want to publish there using an FTP software like [FileZilla](https://filezilla-project.org/) (OpenSource).

I don't know of any online, free webservice that povides you access to webspace where you can publish any content you like and create folders, so that uploading your qgis2web output folder could be published there and would work on the www. There might be some options if you have a substription with a company (like companies providing internet/telephone access). I used to have like 15 years earlier a contract that included a basic webspace. Nowadays however, it will be likely to come in the form of cloud-space - a place where you can save fotos and documents, but in most cases that probably won't work with your qgis2web output folder.

Comment: Github Pages is a free option, if not an open one. You'll need to figure out very basic git, but that can be done via the Github Windows client.