# Publishing map created by qgis2web on CMS

Tags: qgis, export, html, qgis2web, content-management-system

I have a problem with the publication of a qgis2web export on a CMS (another than Wordpress). I have an error when I put `.js`/`.ttf`/`.woff2` files:

> these files are not accepted by the CMS.

Someone has already had this problem?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can see from your description, this won't be possible - to give an answer, even if not a solution. If you use a CMS, you only have limited acceess to the server (by purpose!). You can't (or should not) bypass these restrictions. For a solution of your problem, you should speek to your system administrator to ask what you can/are allowed to do there. There might be security concerns that limits your ability to upload whatever you want. So only a conversation about the the actual configuration of the server, user rights etc. could be able to tell you what you can do (and how).

A CMS is a kind of intermediate system between you as an end-user and the server. It is here to allow you doing certain simple things (updating a website for example), without changing too much (corparate design, server configuration etc.) and without any knowledge of server technologies. So there is a reason why you access the server via an intermediate CMS and to remove the limitations normally also means removing the reasons why you use a CMS.

Normally, if you work with CMS, you don't have access to upload files and whole folders with their content via FTP. This would be the minimum requirement for uploading the qgis2web folders. So everything depends on the system, server configuration and user rights in your particular case.

See here as well: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/392867/88814